# How to get message before opening file in read-only as it is already in use?

Tags: vba, outlook

I copied and adapted VBA code to open a file:

```vb
Public Sub open_workload_spreadsheet()

    Dim xExcelFile As String
    Dim xExcelApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xWb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xWs As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim xExcelRange As Excel.Range
    
    xExcelFile = "R:\Workload Meeting Log.xlsx"
    
    Set xExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xWb = xExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(xExcelFile)

    xExcelApp.Visible = True

End Sub
```

Normally when opening a file that someone else has open a message pops up.

When using the code above no message pops up, it opens a read-only copy.
Is there a way to display the message if someone else is using it?

Comment: What happens if you do `xExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(xExcelFile, ReadOnly:=False)`?

Comment: Put the `Visible` line before you open the file

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but neither of those seem to work. It still opens a read-only version without the error message opening first.